# what is difference between int32_t main() and int main()

Tags: c++

I've seen some people use `int main()` for the main function while some use `int32_t main()`. What is the difference between both and where to use which.

Comment: I've never seen anyone use `int32_t main`. It is confusing, though on most platforms `int32_t` is just a typedef for `int`

Comment: `int32_t main` is not a standard `main` signature, but on some systems `int32_t` might be just an alias for `int`.

Comment: They're both wrong, so not much different.  Use `int main(void)`

Comment: @WilliamPursell It depends on the language. In C++ `int main()` is correct. In C it's `int main(void)`

Comment: The standards require implementations to support `int main()`, but do not require support of `int32_t main()`.      You may get lucky (or unlucky, depending on how you look at it) and find that `int32_t` and `int` happen to be the same type with your implementation (compiler and library) - but the standards don't require that, so the code may not build correctly on different implementations.

Comment: @WilliamPursell - `int main()` is correct in both C and C++.   `int main(void)` is a stylistic preference.

Comment: @ThomasSablik: `int main(void);` and `int main();` only have different meaning in C *if the semicolon is present*.  With a `{` instead of a `;`, the meaning is identical.

Comment: @ThomasSablik C17 6.7.6.3/14 "An empty list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function specifies that the function has no parameters."

Comment: On platforms where `int` is not 32-bits, the `int32_t main()` will convert the return code (to the OS) to a 32-bit value.  This may cause issues with the operating system when the operating system is not expecting 32-bits (such as 16-bits or 64-bits).

Comment: Choose one of C or C++ and delete the other tag. If you want to ask about both, post separate questions. Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about interactions or differences between the languages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(This answer is for C.)

For a hosted C implementation (in contrast to a “freestanding” or “embedded” implementation, the 2018 standard says, in 5.1.2.2.1 1 that `main` shall be defined with a return type of `int`, except that an implementation may define other acceptable definitions. Specifically, it just says the return type shall be `int`, not a type that is just compatible with or the same width as `int`.

What is `int32_t`? It is specified by 7.20, which discusses `<stdint.h>`. 7.20 1 says this header declares various integer types. 7.20.1.1 says “The typedef name `intN_t` designates a signed integer type with width *N*, no padding bits, and a two’s complement representation…” It does not say these types are necessarily the same as the types `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, and so on, even if their properties match. A “typedef name” is an alias for another type, not a type by itself, but the `int32_t` typedef name could be a name for some type other than `int`, even a type that is otherwise indistinguishable from `int`.

Thus:

- Your C implementation could have two types `int` and `int32_t` that have the same properties except for the fact they are different types, where the latter is a typedef name for some built-in type. If so, these are different types, and `int32_t main(void)` does not satisfy the requirement of 5.1.2.2.1 1 unless your C implementation specifically documents that `main` may be defined this way.
- Your C implementation could have `int` being a 16-bit type while `int32_t` is a typedef name for `long`. Again, `int32_t main(void)` would not satisfy 5.1.2.2.1 1.
- Your C implementation could have `int32_t` being a typedef name for `int`. In this case, `int32_t main(void)` would satisfy 5.1.2.2.1 1.

There is really no point to using `int32_t`, though. `int` accomplishes all that is necessary.

### Addendum

There is some discussion in the comments that `int main()` is wrong for C. C 2018 5.1.2.2.2.1 1 says that `main` may be defined in a way “equivalent” to the forms it shows, `int main(void)` and `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. When a function is defined using `()` for the parameter list, the function is defined to have no parameters, and this is equivalent to using `(void)`. (Note that using `()` in a declaration that is not a definition leaves it unspecified whether there are any parameters, but a definition settles it.)

Comment: There are even a couple of examples of `int main()` being used within the standard – 6.5.3.4/8 (EXAMPLE 3) and 6.7.6.3/20 (EXAMPLE 4).

Answer (score 0):

The [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) has a pretty clear cut answer to this.

> ##### 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup
>
> 1. The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no parameters:
>
>    ```
>    int main(void) { /* ... */ }
>    ```
>
>    or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
>
>    ```
>    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
>    ```
>
>    or equivalent; or in some other implementation-defined manner

Using `int32_t` would be by definition "non-standard". In practice, almost all architectures are simply going to declare `int32_t` as `typedef int int32_t`, so it's unlikely to be a problem, but it's always a bad idea.